# Chemfig - is it worth to invest in? Reactions and mechanisms

Tags: chemfig

It's probably a silly question, but I wanted to hear more experienced people in using `chemfig` package and generally if it is worth to invest in? Normally I've done my reactions and mechanisms in ChemDraw like many others. However, I have been using LaTeX for a couple of years and gotten quite familiar with it. Though, I am unsure if it is worth to "invest" and learn `chemfig` to do my drawings, reactions and mechanisms. I do not enjoy having all these pictures in the document and it is seemingly easier to fix if the code is wrong instead of making changes in the ChemDraw sheet. I can see a potential gain for simple molecules, but as soon you are getting into reactions and mechanisms, would the time needed for writing the code not surpass the time it would have been done in ChemDraw? I am aware that different stages of familiarity increases the workflow.

All inputs are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally I found peace in ChemFig. It's worth putting some minutes. With the help of experts in the community here, you save a bunch of minutes

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Chemdraw doesn't save to PDF. PDF images can be enlarged without being "blurred", and are perfect for inserting into LaTeX files.

Yes, more complex reactions require more time to do in ChemFig, but in ChemDraw as well. But much of the code from one reaction can be copied and adapted to another reaction, which saves a lot of time.

When I first started using ChemFig, it took me a few days to come up with a not-too-complex reaction mechanism.
The reaction below, after months of using ChemFIg, took a few hours. some hours.

[image]

Comment: ChemDraw can save EPS files on all platforms, and those can be converted to PDF. On the Mac, ChemDraw can save PDF directly.

Comment: Thanks for the info